# Disable button after adding task to task list

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to add some items to task list and disable button each time. When page loads it works fine.

I'd like to also disable button after adding each task.

If you add a new task and press submit button it works fine. But if the user choose pressing 'Enter' button instead of submit it becomes enabled.

What should it be done to disable submit button if the user prefers 'Enter' button instead of submit button ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

                // By default, submit button is disabled
                document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;

                // Enable button only if there is text in the input field
                document.querySelector('#task').onkeyup = () => {
                    document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = false;
                };

                document.querySelector('#new-task').onsubmit = () => {

                    // Create new item for list
                    const li = document.createElement('li');
                    li.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#task').value;

                    // Add new item to task list
                    document.querySelector('#tasks').append(li);

                    // Clear input field and disable button again
                    document.querySelector('#task').value = '';
                    document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;

                    // Stop form from submitting
                    return false;
                };

            });
        </script>
        <title>Tasks</title>
    </head>
```

Body part of the html.

```
    <body>
        <h1>Tasks</h1>
        <ul id="tasks">
        </ul>
        <form id="new-task">
            <input id="task" autocomplete="off" autofocus placeholder="New Task" type="text">
            <input id="submit" type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `Enter` button here?

Comment: Enter button on the keyboard.

Comment: Try using set/get Attribute? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the `enter` button, your `onkeyup` event handler changes the submit button disabled state to `false`, and the enter works.

Instead, listen to the `input` event of the #task box, and enable/disable the submit button according to the changes in the content. This will also handle the case in which submit is enabled after the text was deleted.

```
// Enable button only if there is text in the input field
document.querySelector('#task').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = e.target.value === '';
});
```

**Example:**

```js
// By default, submit button is disabled
document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;

// Enable button only if there is text in the input field
document.querySelector('#task').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = e.target.value === '';
});

document.querySelector('#new-task').onsubmit = () => {

  // Create new item for list
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#task').value;

  // Add new item to task list
  document.querySelector('#tasks').append(li);

  // Clear input field and disable button again
  document.querySelector('#task').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;

  // Stop form from submitting
  return false;
};
```

```css
#submit:disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<h1>Tasks</h1>
<ul id="tasks">
</ul>
<form id="new-task">
  <input id="task" autocomplete="off" autofocus placeholder="New Task" type="text">
  <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you press `enter` key the event listner `keyup` is firing. You have to put the enable of button here in conditions

```
 document.querySelector('#task').onkeyup = (e) => {
                   if(e.which === 13){
                     return; // When user enter key press  
                   }
                    document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = false;
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

I was watching Harvard CS50 Web Programming Course and I'd like to share another solution. This is not a part of homework, assignment etc. so I feel free to share solution.

Basically we enable button if there is text in the input field.

```
// Enable button only if there is text in the input field
document.querySelector('#task').onkeyup = () => {
    if (document.querySelector('#task').value.length > 0)
        document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = false;
    else
        document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;
};
```

```js
// By default, submit button is disabled
document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;

// Enable button only if there is text in the input field
document.querySelector('#task').onkeyup = () => {
    if (document.querySelector('#task').value.length > 0)
        document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = false;
    else
        document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;
};

document.querySelector('#new-task').onsubmit = () => {

    // Create new item for list
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#task').value;

    // Add new item to task list
    document.querySelector('#tasks').append(li);

    // Clear input field and disable button again
    document.querySelector('#task').value = '';
    document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;

    // Stop form from submitting
    return false;
};
```

```css
#submit:disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<h1>Tasks</h1>
<ul id="tasks">
</ul>
<form id="new-task">
    <input id="task" autocomplete="off" autofocus placeholder="New Task" type="text">
    <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```